# auto login in webview returns blank page with the username

Tags: javascript, android, webview, autologin

i'm trying to make an app to load and display a webpage on a webview, i want the user has not to login as many times he runs the app so i want to auto fill the fields "username" and "password". I have tried many methods that i found in google but some of them didn't work, the username and password fields stills empty, and the others just opens a blank page with the username value.

Here is part of the code for the web page i'm trying to autolog:

```html
<form action="#" onSubmit="MAIN.doAuth(); return false;">

              <div class="user_id">
 
               <label for="user_id">User ID</label>
 
               <div class="text_frame">
 
                 <input id="user_id" type="text" value="" maxlength="20">

                  <span class="button_clear_text" onclick=""></span>

                </div>
              
  </div>
              
  <div class="password">

                 <label for="password">Password</label>
 
               <div class="text_frame">
 
                 <input id="password" type="password" value="" maxlength="20">

                  <span class="button_clear_text" onclick=""></span>
  
              </div>
              
 </div>
              
 <div class="submit">

                <input id="button_login" type="submit" value="LOGIN">
 
             </div>
            
</form>
```

And here is my mainActivity:

```
public class FirstScreenActivity<DrawerLayout> extends Activity {

ArrayAdapter adapter;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
public String[] names;
public String username = "oscar";
private ListView mDrawerList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.first_screen);
    View header = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.cabecera, null);
    View footer = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footer, null);
    this.mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer); // list view

    // Load an array of options names
    names = getResources().getStringArray(
            R.array.nav_options);

 // Set previous array as adapter of the list
   /* ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);*/
    mDrawerList.addHeaderView(header);
    mDrawerList.addFooterView(footer);
    adapter = new AdaptadorList(
            this,
            DataSource.TAREAS);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    WebView webView = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://m-komtrax.komatsu.co.jp/m/klc/c/");
    //webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
       /* @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView v, String url) {
            v.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }*/
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView v, String url) {
            v.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsById('password').value = 'username';");
            //v.loadUrl("javascript: document.getElementById('user_id').innerHTML  = 'hello';");
            //v.loadUrl("javascript:document.querySelector('input[id=user_id]').value = '"+ username +"';");
            //v.loadUrl("javascript:document.forms['login'].submit()");
        }
    });

}
```

please help me, i need fill the username and password fields with a value that i previous going to store. thanks

Comment: Guys any idea about the problem? please i need a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

I had faced a pretty similar issue.The solution here is just a single line of code to call the super class use super keyword after the onPageFinished method add this line of code.

```
super.onPageFinished(view, url);
```

That's it all.Hope it helped
Peace!!

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise, be sure you tailor your answer to *this* question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: @EdCottrell the same answer really answers both the question but since i don't know this rule here will be trying to close it as duplicate.Thank you for making me aware of this.